# Laravel - ErrorException (E_ERROR) Undefined variable

Tags: php, laravel, laragon

I'm trying to add a dropdown menu to auth.register but I get error (Undefined variable). I have tried a lot of things but nothing happens.

I have made changes in:

RegisterController.php, Register.blade.php, web.php

---

> RegisterController.php: Add this function:

```
public function combo() {
    $roles = rol::all();
    dd($roles);
    return view('auth.register',compact('roles'));
}
```

---

> web.php:

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('auth.register', 'auth.RegisterController@combo');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

---

> register.blade.php: Try this but get the error message:

```
<select name="id_rol" id="id_rol" class="form-control">
    <option value="" disabled>Choose an option</option>
    @foreach ($roles as $rol)
        <option value="{{ $rol->id }}">
            {{ $rol->nombre }}
        </option>
    @endforeach
 </select>
```

---

I need that the variable "roles" can be used in register.blade.php

Comment: $roles = rol::all(); you think you did that right ?

Comment: Can you maybe show the whole RegisterController?

Comment: Route::get('auth.register', 'auth.RegisterController@combo'); how an url be like this ??

Comment: which variable is it saying is undefined? what's the full error?

Comment: that's the file name - what's the full error message?

Comment: This is the full error: ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Undefined variable: roles (View: C:\laragon\www\SIGEC\resources\views\auth\register.blade.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, `Auth::routes();` already has route('/register') pointing to a different function

so comment out `Auth::routes();` and use your Route::get('/register', 'auth.RegisterController@combo');

Comment: please remove excessive font size and boldness

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use

```
return view('auth.register', ['roles' => $roles]);
```

Assuming that $roles is a standard eloquent collection with results it should work fine

Beside that you should check that the route is working. If you autogenerated the Auth path and you use the

```
Auth::routes();
```

inside your routes, your route will be ignored if put below that line.

So, check that your routes are all in place, otherwise you could be loading the standard RegisterController method for your route but still loading the new view (without the $roles variable)

If you need to call a custom function, in web.php you should call the path before the Auth::routes() or (better) override the method

without editing the Auth::routes(), you can simply override the showRegistrationForm() method inside your RegistrationController.php

Auth\RegistrationController.php

```
public function showRegistrationForm() {

    $roles = rol::all();
    dd($roles);
    return view('auth.register', ['roles' => $roles]);

}
```

and remove your

```
Route::get('auth.register', 'auth.RegisterController@combo');
```

since its ignored (laravel checks for the first occurrence and the Auth::routes() is read before your custom route)

Another Edit for future reference:
if you use the CLI command

```
php artisan route:list
```

You wget the list of all the method called by your routes and see if your setup is correct

Comment: Sorry I edited my answer because it could be a route problem => are you calling the combo() method correctly? is the dd() shown?

Comment: Can you show how load the standard RegisterController method? Thanks

Comment: Edited my answer